# What is wrong with this Reflection.Emit for value conversion delegates?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dynamic-memory-allocation, reflection.emit, linq-expressions

Sorry for this long question but I feel I have to provide a bit more background as my issue is very specific.

### Bigger picture

I am developing on a Unity tool to be used specifically for [Embedded Linux platforms](https://docs.unity.com/embeddedlinux/en/manual/Installation).

This environment has certain restrictions such as in specific being quite sensible with runtime allocations (GC causing hickups etc) -> we won't to avoid any form of runtime allocation or better said de-allocation.

#### Where I come from

In this tool one main feature is the conversion of types.

The original (POC) implementation broken down looked somewhat like e.g.

```
public interface IValue
{
    bool AsInt(out int result);
    bool AsFloat(out float result);
    bool AsDouble(out double result);
    //...
    // explicit conversions for all supported value types
}

public abstract Value<T> : IValue
{
    [SerializeField] private T m_Value;

    public T TypedValue
    {
        get => m_Value;
        set => m_Value = value;
    }

    private bool TryCast<TTarget>(out TTarget result)
    {
        if (m_Value is TTarget target)
        {
            result = target;
            return true;
        }

        result = default;
        return false;
    }

    public virtual bool AsInt(out int result)
    {
        return TryCast(out result);
    }

    public virtual bool AsFloat(out float result)
    {
        return TryCast(out result);
    }

    public virtual bool AsDouble(out double result)
    {
        return TryCast(out result);
    }

    //...
}
```

and as implementation example (there are more complex conversions and many types - this is just for understanding the concept)

```
[Serializable]
public class BoolOriginal : Value<bool>
{
    public override bool AsInt(out int result)
    {
        result = TypedValue ? 1 : 0;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool AsFloat(out float result)
    {
        result = TypedValue ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool AsDouble(out double result)
    {
        result = TypedValue ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Original issue/limitation

Now the big "issue" with this is - as soon as you want to add support for a new type you have to hard code it into the interface and at least the base class. As this tool is supposed to be a readonly **package** this is something we can not do later on.

### My first "solution" attempt

So I thought I could solve this by instead introducing generics and do something like e.g.

```
public interface IValue
{
    bool As<TTarget>(out TTarget result);
}

public abstract class Value<T> : IValue
{
    [SerializeField] private T m_Value;

    public T TypedValue
    {
        get => m_Value;
        set => m_Value = value;
    }

    public bool As<TTarget>(out TTarget result)
    {
        if (TypedValue is TTarget target)
        {
            result = target;
            return true;
        }

        if (Conversions.TryGetValue(typeof(TTarget), out var conversion))
        {
            result = (TTarget)conversion(TypedValue);
            return true;
        }

        if (k_DefaultConversions.TryGetValue(typeof(TTarget), out var defaultConversion))
        {
            result = (TTarget)defaultConversion(TypedValue);
            return true;
        }

        result = default;
        return false;
    }

    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Func<T, object>> k_DefaultConversions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<T, object>>
    {
        { typeof(string), value => value.ToString() },
    };

    protected abstract IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Func<T, object>> Conversions { get; }
}
```

and then simply let inheritors implement their own conversions

```
public class BoolPlain : Value<bool>
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Func<bool, object>> k_Conversions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<bool, object>>
    {
        { typeof(int), value => value ? 1 : 0 },
        { typeof(float), value => value ? 1.0f : 0.0f },
        { typeof(double), value => value ? 1.0 : 0.0 }
    };

    protected override IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Func<bool, object>> Conversions => k_Conversions;
}
```

This works fine - but introduced **boxing allocations**! Again this doesn't seem a huge thing but in this specific embedded environment it kinda is!

### So what now?

I am now looking into two things to go around this

#### Linq Expressions

```
public abstract class Value<T> : IValue
{
    private T m_Value;

    public T TypedValue
    {
        get => m_Value;
        set => m_Value = value;
    }

    public bool As<TTarget>(out TTarget result)
    {
        if (TypedValue is TTarget target)
        {
            result = target;
            return true;
        }

        if (Conversions.TryGetValue(typeof(TTarget), out var conversion) && conversion is Func<T, TTarget> converter)
        {
            result = converter(TypedValue);
            return true;
        }

        if (k_DefaultConversions.TryGetValue(typeof(TTarget), out var defaultConversion) && defaultConversion is Func<T, TTarget> defaultConverter)
        {
            result = defaultConverter(TypedValue);
            return true;
        }

        result = default;
        return false;
    }

    protected static Delegate CreateConverter<TOutput>(Func<T, TOutput> converter)
    {
        var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "input");
        var body = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(converter), input);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, input);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Delegate> k_DefaultConversions = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
    {
        { typeof(string), CreateConverter<string>(v => v.ToString()) },
    };

    protected abstract IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Delegate> Conversions { get; }
}
```

and implementation

```
public class BoolValue : Value<bool>
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Delegate> k_Conversions = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
    {
        { typeof(int), CreateConverter<int>(v => v ? 1 : 0) },
        { typeof(float), CreateConverter<float>(v => v ? 1.0f : 0.0f) },
        { typeof(double), CreateConverter<double>(v => v ? 1.0 : 0.0) }
    };

    protected override IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Delegate> Conversions => k_Conversions;
}
```

This at least halves the allocation compared to the plain generic way above and seems very slightly more efficient.

### Question

So as alternative I wanted to try `Reflection.Emit` instead and do the following (with some ChatGPT and research help not gonna lie ^^)

```
private static readonly valueType = typeof(T);

protected static Delegate CreateConverter<TOutput>(Func<T, TOutput> converter)
{
    var outType = typeof(TOutput);

    var method = new DynamicMethod(
        "Convert_" + valueType.Name + "_To_" + outType.Name,
        outType,
        new[] { valueType },
        typeof(Value<>).Module,
        true);

    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, converter.Method, null);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, TOutput>));
}
```

But this always gives me an

```
InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in (wrapper dynamic-method) object:Convert_Boolean_To_String (bool): IL_0001: call      0x00000001
```

I tried a lot of different iterations - also using `OpCodes.Callvirt` instead - but this issue persists.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Is it maybe an issue that the base class used in `typeof(Value<>).Module` is generic?

**[Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PMqEnW)**

---

At this point I'm also open for any other alternative that provides the desired flexibility while maintaining the allocation restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a delegate, you need to call its `Invoke` method. This means you need the `converter` itself. You can't use the `.Method` property as you don't know what type of method it is (instance/static) or whether it involves any shuffling due to an extra or missing `this`.

So if you *really* wanted to use this method (don't, see below), then you would need to pass in the original `Func`, something like:

```cs
protected static Delegate CreateConverter<TOutput>(Func<T, TOutput> converter)
{
    var outType = typeof(TOutput);

    var method = new DynamicMethod(
        "Convert_" + valueType.Name + "_To_" + outType.Name,
        outType,
        new[] { typeof(Func<T, TOutput>), valueType, },
        typeof(Value<>).Module,
        true);

    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Func<T, TOutput>).GetMethod("Invoke"), null);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Func<T, TOutput>, T, TOutput>));
}
```

But obviously this makes no sense to do. If all you wanted was to return a `Func<T, TOutput>` as a `Delegate`, you don't need dynamic methods, you could just return the delegate you already have.

So just cast use your original delegate.

```
// we expect each Delegate to be a Func<T, Type> where Type is the key in the dictionay
protected abstract IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Delegate> Conversions { get; }

public bool As<TTarget>(out TTarget result)
{
    if (TypedValue is TTarget result)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (Conversions.TryGetValue(typeof(TTarget), out var conversion) && conversion is Func<T, TTarget> converter)
    {
        result = converter(TypedValue);
        return true;
    }

    if (k_DefaultConversions.TryGetValue(typeof(TTarget), out var defaultConversion) && defaultConversion is Func<T, TTarget> defaultConverter)
    {
        result = defaultConverter(TypedValue);
        return true;
    }

    result = default;
    return false;
}
```

And then you can just declare your dictionaries like this:

```cs
public class BoolPlain : Value<bool>
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Delegate> k_Conversions = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
    {
        { typeof(int),    new Func<bool, int>   (value => value ? 1 : 0) },
        { typeof(float),  new Func<bool, float> (value => value ? 1.0f : 0.0f) },
        { typeof(double), new Func<bool, double>(value => value ? 1.0 : 0.0) }
    };

    protected override IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Delegate> Conversions => k_Conversions;
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RGkBEY)

Comment: Ha! That makes a lot of sense thanks! I tried using `{ typeof(int), (bool value) => value ? 1 : 0 }` and gave up after that :'D

Comment: Note that you would still have problems if overriders don't know about *other* overriders.

Comment: Yeah it is still far from being perfect .. I am currently considering to take a complete different route and use a static master dictionary and according "RegisterConversion" so we can inject any type to any type conversions instead of only going source -> target - but especially the bottom snippet simplifies the whole thing a lot ^^ Though I kinda became friend with the CreateConversion at least enforce a certain signature :D

Comment: You could still enforce it, eg you could move the dictionary to the base class `void RegisterConverter<TTarget>(Func<T, TTarget> converter) { _conversion.Add(typeof(TTarget), converter); }` and have the derived class call that.